# JMonkeyEngine, how to remove something from GeometryBatchFactory.optimize()?

Tags: java, optimization, vertex-buffer, jmonkeyengine

I am working on a "minecraft clone" using JME and I have come across a problem that I can't have too many blocks on the screen without destroying the fps. As of right now when I try to load 1000 blocks the fps drops to around 49. I have optimized it so that if two blocks touch each other their faces that are touching aren't drawn.

So after doing some research I discovered I can optimize the rootNode using GeomteryBatchFactory.optimize() which helped a lot. However, the problem is that now I cannot remove any of the blocks because they are still rendered. Is there any way/method to remove the blocks from the optimization?

I also found another method of optimizing using a vertex buffer. After doing more research I realize that this could help, however I couldn't find any examples demonstrating how to use it correctly. So if you think that using a vertex buffer is the better way of going around this problem could you possibly lead me to some tutorials? Thank you.

Also, I know this question isn't exactly "code" based but I don't really know where else to go right now because the JME forums are down. Sorry.

Comment: JMonkeyEngine is not the same as Java ME.

Comment: @immibis what does this have to do with Java ME? I just wrote JME to abbreviate JMonkeyEngine

Comment: java-me is one of the tags; I'll remove it for you

Comment: You want to organise your blocks into chunks (probably around 16 by 16 by 128 in size); that is a single rendered object. Do not try to render blocks 1 by 1 (I know it makes life a lot simpler but it destroys your graphics performance). I wrote something about why chunks are used [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/130719/51232)